# Where is setting for RetainSameConnection stored?

Tags: ssis

RetainSameConnection property on project-level connections.

If I change to true (from default of false) and choose not to save the package file I used to make the change then the setting will be retained but none of the files in source control have changed.  Where is this value being stored?!

Value is stored even after closing/reopening VS and restarting machine.

Also:
If you specify RetainSameConnection=true at the project-file level (.dtproj) the RetainSameConnection property drop-down (viewed via Properties tab) in VS will show false but the behaviour will be true.  While I would expect behaviour to be true it's misleading that the drop-down value doesn't conform & I'd like to understand why it doesn't.

If you create a boolean project param with value of true & parameterise RetainSameConnection property of the project connection then behaviour will be true and you can no longer change the value of the drop-down.  This is exactly what I'd expect.

If you edit and save the connection properties it will set DTS:Retain="True" on the conmgr file.  This again doesn't cause the drop-down value to change.  haven't experimented with this as am losing the will slightly.